# Using NSNumberFormatter, how can you use 2 decimal places, yet still retain the whether the user only entered 1 or 2 decimals?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, floating-point, decimal, nsnumberformatter

I know all about the way decimal points are stored, but am not sure how I can get around displaying them correctly to satisfy my requirements.

I have a field that allows the user to enter up to a maximum of 2 decimal points. 11.25, 9.9, etc.

However, it's extremely important that the value entered is displayed exactly how it was entered.

For example, I'm entering 9.9 (which is stored likely as 9.8999999999999). Then when displayed to the user, it's being shown as 9.89.

I need this to be displayed as it was written, as 9.9.

Likewise, 11.25 must be displayed as 11.25. If 2 decimals were entered by the user, 2 must be displayed. If only 1 was entered by the user, 1 must be displayed, regardless of how it is stored (i.e. 9.899999999999)

Answer (score 2):

For exact decimal numbers use `NSDecimalNumber`, that way you will not get 9.899999999999 but 9.9.

The rounding mode can be set with the method `setRoundingMode:` of the `NSNumberFormatter` class to one of the `NSNumberFormatterRoundingMode` constants.

The display format can be set with the method `setFormat:` of the `NSNumberFormatter`.

In order to display the number of decimal digits entered you either need to save the string or the number of digits. Once it is changed to a numeric value from a textual representation how it was entered is lost.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know more about you user interface but you need to use `NSNumber` and the `NSNumberFormatter`

**First**, get the user input as a number from the input string using a basic `NSNumberformatter`. The number will get stored as it was entered (e.g. "1.23" is stored as 1.23, "6.3" is stored as 6.3):

```
NSString *inputstring = inputTextField.text;
NSNumberFormatter * inputFormatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
NSNumber * inputNumber = [inputFormatter numberFromString:inputstring];
```

**Second**, when you display the number use a more precise `NSNumberFormatter` to limit the number of decimal places:

```
NSNumberFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
outputFormatter.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];     // make sure to show the number with the local setting of the device!
outputFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
outputFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator = YES;           // your choice...
outputFormatter.groupingSize = 3;
outputFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2;             // <-- here you limit the number of decimal places
```

and show the number localized in a label, textfield or what ever:

```
outputLabel.text = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"%@", [outputFormatter stringForObjectValue:inputNumber]];
```

This will limit the output to max. 2 decimal places but will also show not more decimal places than the user was entering.

Comment: This helped me a lot in the reverse sense: convert a string with varying separators (decimal/group) into an NSDecimalNumber.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a custom subclass of `NSFormatter`. It would use strings as the object value, to preserve exactly what the user entered. Your model would also have to store the values as strings, if you need to preserve exactly what the user entered. As Zaph pointed out, if you convert to a numeric scalar type (e.g. `double`) or to `NSNumber`, the exact nature of what the user entered is lost.

You could either implement the validation methods of `NSFormatter` yourself or your custom formatter class would *use* (not *inherit*) `NSNumberFormatter` and leverage it to validate the input (without having your formatter output `NSNumber`s). If you implement validation yourself, you have to be careful about locale. For example, using the appropriate decimal separator for the locale.

Your class's implementation of `-stringForObjectValue:` would return a copy of the input (autoreleased, if you're not using ARC).

Its implementation of `-getObjectValue:forString:errorDescription:` would check if the current string is valid. If not, it will return `NO`. If you're implementing validation yourself, you would write that code. If you're leveraging `NSNumberFormatter`, you would declare an `NSNumber*` variable and call the same method on your number formatter instance, passing the address of your `NSNumber*` variable as the object to get. If it returns `NO`, your method should return `NO`. If it returns `YES`, set `*anObject` to a copy of `string` (autoreleased, if not using ARC) and return `YES`.

If you want validation of partial strings, override `-isPartialStringValid:proposedSelectedRange:originalString:originalSelectedRange:errorDescription:`. If you're implementing validation on your own, you write the code. If you're leveraging `NSNumberFormatter`, call through to your number formatter instance. I believe you need to have set `partialStringValidationEnabled` on the number formatter object when you set it up.